# Is this the proper way of doing conditional displaying?

Tags: css, reactjs

Sorry again for another post :

Here is what i wanted to achieve :
[image: On wide screen]

[image: On small screen]

This is what i managed to do but i was wondering if there was a cleaner way to do it :

```js
import "../styles/SponsorUs.css";
import svg from "../assets/parcours.svg";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";



export function SponsorUs() {
    const [isScreenSmall, setIsScreenSmall] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handleResize = () => {
            if (window.innerWidth <= 1000) {
                setIsScreenSmall(true);
            } else {
                setIsScreenSmall(false);
            }
        };
        handleResize();
        window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='global'>

            <div className='titleSponsor'>
                {!isScreenSmall  && <img className='titleSponsorImg' src={svg} alt=''/>}

                <h1>Le 4l Trophy, c’est quoi?</h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp1'>Le 4L Trophy est un raid étudiant organisé depuis plus de 20 ans au Maroc.
                    Il s'agit d'un défi sportif et humanitaire qui réunit chaque année des milliers d'étudiants
                    venus de toute la France et d'ailleurs. Le but ? Parcourir plus de 6000 kilomètres à bord de 4L,
                    tout en acheminant des fournitures scolaires pour les enfants défavorisés du Maroc.</p>
                <h1>Notre itinéraire </h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp2'>Notre itinéraire pour le 4L Trophy est un véritable parcours du combattant
                    !
                    Nous affronterons les routes les plus difficiles du Maroc, à travers les montagnes,
                    les déserts et les plaines arides. Nous serons confrontés à des défis physiques et mentaux,
                    mais nous sommes prêts à relever le défi !</p>
                {isScreenSmall  && <img className='titleSponsorImg2' src={svg} alt=''/>}
                <h1>Trailer du 4L Trophy</h1>

                <h1>Vous êtes captivés par notre projet ? </h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

And there is my css file.

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins");

.titleSponsor{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

.titleSponsor h1{
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-left: 5%;
    text-align: left;
}

.titleSponsor p{
    padding-left: 5%;
    text-align: justify;
    font-size : 15px;
}

.titleSponsorp1{
    width : 70%;
}
.titleSponsorp2{
    width : 58%;
}
.titleSponsorImg{
    width : 25%;
    height : 25%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-right: 5%;
    float: right;
}

.titleSponsorImg2{
    width : 25%;
    height : 25%;
    padding-top: 5%;
    padding-right: 15%;
}

@media (min-width: 768px){
    }
```

Please give me an honnest point of view it is my first project for web development.

Do i really need to do a useEffect or mediaqueries are sufficient?
Please enlighten me

Comment: Opinion based question are not allowed on SO (the title seems with opinion). (PS: C'est "d'une 4L" pas "de 4L")

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this with media queries in CSS and not have to use state:

```css
.titleSponsorImg {
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .titleSponsorImg {
    display: block;
  }

  .titleSponsorImg2 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```
import "../styles/SponsorUs.css";
import svg from "../assets/parcours.svg";

export function SponsorUs() {
    return (
        <div className='global'>

            <div className='titleSponsor'>
                <img className='titleSponsorImg' src={svg} alt=''/>

                <h1>Le 4l Trophy, c’est quoi?</h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp1'>Le 4L Trophy est un raid étudiant organisé depuis plus de 20 ans au Maroc.
                    Il s'agit d'un défi sportif et humanitaire qui réunit chaque année des milliers d'étudiants
                    venus de toute la France et d'ailleurs. Le but ? Parcourir plus de 6000 kilomètres à bord de 4L,
                    tout en acheminant des fournitures scolaires pour les enfants défavorisés du Maroc.</p>
                <h1>Notre itinéraire </h1>
                <p className='titleSponsorp2'>Notre itinéraire pour le 4L Trophy est un véritable parcours du combattant
                    !
                    Nous affronterons les routes les plus difficiles du Maroc, à travers les montagnes,
                    les déserts et les plaines arides. Nous serons confrontés à des défis physiques et mentaux,
                    mais nous sommes prêts à relever le défi !</p>
                <img className='titleSponsorImg2' src={svg} alt=''/>
                <h1>Trailer du 4L Trophy</h1>

                <h1>Vous êtes captivés par notre projet ? </h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```